# Ansible - installed RPM packages for multiple servers

Tags: ansible

I am trying to query installed RPM packages on every server, and export to the JSON file.
So far I have managed to export one JSON file for each server. Server name is the JSON file name.

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
    - name: RPM packages query
      shell: rpm -qa --queryformat '%{NAME} %{VERSION}\n' 
      register: query 

    - name: list report
      debug:
        var: query.stdout_lines

    - local_action: copy content="{{ query.stdout_lines }}" dest="/home/user_name/{{ ansible_hostname }}.json"
```

Output, where the server name is the file name - **host_name1.json**:

```json
[
  "spice-glib 0.35",
  "keyutils-libs-devel 1.5.8",
  "mapserver 1.0",
  "perl-HTTP-Cookies 6.01",
  "open-vm-tools-desktop 11.0.5",
  "libreport-python 2.1.11",
]
```

**Question**: how do I export the entire `query.stdout_lines` result from all servers into the one file, including the host name, for example:

```json
[**host_name1_here**
]

[
  "spice-glib 0.35",
  "keyutils-libs-devel 1.5.8",
  "mapserver 1.0",
  "perl-HTTP-Cookies 6.01",
  "open-vm-tools-desktop 11.0.5",
  "libreport-python 2.1.11",
]

[**host_name2_here**
]

[
  "spice-glib 0.35",
  "keyutils-libs-devel 1.5.8",
  "mapserver 1.0",
  "perl-HTTP-Cookies 6.01",
]
```

Or something like that.
Or is there another, perhaps better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```yaml
- hosts: all
  become: no
  vars:
    output_file: details.csv
  tasks:
    - block:
        - name: RPM packages query
          shell: rpm -qa --queryformat '%{NAME} %{VERSION}\n' 
          register: rpmdata
          changed_when: false

        - name: Empty existing file if already exists
          copy:
            dest: "{{ output_file }}"
            content: 'Details'
          run_once: yes
          delegate_to: localhost

        - name: Add details to file
          lineinfile:
            path: "{{ output_file }}"
            line: "[{{ inventory_hostname }}]\n\
              [{{ rpmdata.stdout }}]\n\n"
          delegate_to: localhost
```

A number of changes had to be made to your original code.

Note the below:

1. Using `shell` module means running any command leaves Ansible changed status to true for that task. Given your task does not make any changes, I have made the change flag to `false`
2. The second task should be to clean an existing output file or create file if not present.
3. `lineinfile` module can be used to append to a file.
4. As you may have noticed the `delegate_to` will run 2, 3 on localhost which remain a host common to other web servers or the host machine where Ansible is being run from.